# Server and Client program in java: Client needs to start and end the conversation

Tags: java, command-prompt

The client needs to start and end the conversation with the keyword "end." When the client types end and hits enter the server needs to print "the session has ended" and both the client and the server need to close.

The problem I am having is when I end on the client side, the client socket closes, the server prints "the session has ended" but the server socket does not close until you press enter on the server side. <-- this is the bug. I need both to end when you type end and press enter on the client side.

Server -

```
import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 public class Server {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket sSock = new ServerSocket(1201);
        Socket sock = sSock.accept();

        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String msgin = "";
        String msgout ="";

        while(!msgin.equals("end")) {
            msgin = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println(msgin);
            msgout = reader.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF("Server: " + msgout);
            dout.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("ended");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
}
```

Client -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1201);
        System.out.println("Server: This is Server");
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String msgin ="";
        String msgout ="";
        while(!msgin.equals("end")) {
            msgout = reader.readLine();
            if (msgout.equals("end")) {
                sock.close();
            }
            dout.writeUTF("Client: " + msgout);
            msgin = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println(msgin);
        }
        sock.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
       }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and when any of the sides close the socket, it will automatically close the connection in the other side, due to the nature of how sockets work. If you add a sysout or a e.printStackTrace(), you will see that the socket is closing with an exception and the program is ending in the other side to.

However, you may consider implementing a multi-thread application, so you can allow both client and server send and receive messages at any time. In the way it is designed, once one side sends a message, it can only send another one after it receives a message from the other side.

You can check a simple but useful example of client/server chat here: [Server/Multiclient program wont send message to all clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452782/server-multiclient-program-wont-send-message-to-all-clients/)

```
package so52712250;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket sSock = new ServerSocket(1201);
            Socket sock = sSock.accept();

            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String msgin = "";
            String msgout = "";

            while (!msgin.equals("end")) {
                msgin = din.readUTF();
                System.out.println(msgin);
                msgout = reader.readLine();
                dout.writeUTF("Server: " + msgout);
                dout.flush();
            }
            System.out.println("ended");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The sysout message in the catch is what really solved my problem. Thank you for the multi-threading though I need to expand on this chat client for a future project so that helps a lot too.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the scanner is blocking until it receives input.

One possible solution would be to use 2 thread.  One to read from scanner and one to read from stream.  If one ends make sure both threads are cleaned up.